# Shape detection in bmp file using java

Tags: image-processing

I need to detect shape in a .bmp in java. The image can have any shape oval, ellipse or a circle. It'll be like a circle with black boundaries on a white background. I tried using boofCV but couldn't get the desired result. Any other library which will help in this case.

Comment: I don't personally know boofCV. But it sounds like it is base on OpenCV. For which there is a java library. [link](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
If you have problems, you may find help faster if you post what you have tried and what the undesired result was (compared to the desired result).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll look into OpenCV too. I tried detecting the ovals using the example on boofCV site. It was supposed to detect the ovals and shade its boundaries with red colour. It didn't highlight anything. Secondly, my requirement is a bit complex, as I need to detect the ovals and then need to write something on that and use that information for further processing. Let me check OpenCV too if someone has done anything like that using it or not.